# Capturing integer value from HTML using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to capture the value of the integer in the HTML code below

```
<span class="ratingCount">1,602</span>
```

Here I want to store the value 1,602 as an integer in a variable (Let's say $number). Can anyone help me, please ?

Comment: Maybe [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will work?

Comment: I am using Curl to get the whole HTML page and this code is just one part of the page

Comment: Then use a DOM parser, why regex? XPath will be simple: `//span[@class="ratingCount"]/text()`